# Why can't sleep(3) before login check prevent brute force?

Tags: php, authentication, brute-force

In a PHP login script, why wouldn't this pseudocode prevent a brute force attack? Of course it's still possible given enough time, but it's basically useless to brute force anything more than a few characters?

Edit: I'm not asking what the optimal way to make a login script is - just whether or not sleep() is an efficient way of drastically **reducing** the chance of success of brute force attacks.

```
<?php
sleep(2)

if($_POST['password'] == $passwordInDB)
    $loggedIn = true;
else {
   sleep(3) //slow down even more on failed attempts.
   echo "login failed";
}
....
?>
```

**Assumptions:**

1. This is a normal basic website, needing a "better than nothing" attack prevention. Obviously, huge sites with millions of users is a completely different story.
2. Apache is configured with MaxRequestWorkers to 100 for instance (default: 256)
3. Server is powerful enough to handle 100 simultaneous request.

My script would spend 5 seconds to complete a failed request.

Wouldn't the attacker only be able to perform 100*5/60 = 8.3 guesses per second in this case? Which is completely useless for any normal password?

Comment: But hackers dont do this stuff by hand you realise. They use software therefore they have loads of time to keep trying. And your server spends loads of time effort CPU cycles and memory doing nothing for 3 seconds

Comment: this will increase the attack time but hack can easily attack using multi threads, parallel programs in one go.

Comment: In the end, you will only annoy legitimate users. If you want to add security, provide two factor authentication.

Comment: This only slows down the response to that particular request, it has no influence on the other 1,000 requests I am sending to your system at the same time …

Comment: @Cabrra no. While sleeping, the CPU is idle. It is available for other threads.

Comment: I'm aware that you can use multiple simultaneous request, but that's what I don't get - you can't use unlimited simultaneous requests. The server would only be able to handle a limited number of simultaneous requests. So how are you going be able to make 1 000 000 attempts even?

Comment: @misorude But if the server can only handle 100 requests at the same time - it would need to wait 8 seconds (in this example) before it can handle another 100 requests. So how can you brute force with 12,5 guesses per second? This is of course assuming, server have no DDOS protection at all (even just limiting requests per IP would make it more difficult)

Comment: I have no idea where you are pulling those numbers from now.

Comment: @misorude You wrote: "it has no influence on the other 1,000 requests I am sending to your system at the same time" - there's no way a normal PC can handle 1000 requests to login.php at the same time... Depending on configuration, only a few will run at the same time, and the others will wait until script is completed (8 seconds because of sleep). I doubt an average webhost would handle more than 100 simultanious requests on their standard configuration.

Comment: If I wanted to attack your site via brute force, I am not going to do that from my own laptop at home … I am going to use cloud computing instances, those are available  so cheap they are ideal for such a purpose.

Comment: I don't understand how that's relevant, I'm talking about the server here... I'll edit and rephrase my original post.

Comment: a brute force attack isn't time dependant. A hacker will set up a huge array of passwords upto 8 chars and run a loop until it works. The best form of authentication in my eyes, isn't two-step authentication or anything like that. It's have a proper password pattern in place to begin with, longer than 8 chars, containing alphanumeric chars and symbols as well as setting a login attempt limit will reduce the hacking chance drastically .

Comment: also regarding the other comments - a login attempt should will realistically only be <1 sec execution time, a good hack script will check X times before adding a sleep to prevent an overload of requests. However, because logging in isn't to heavy on the resources, they probably don't have too many breaks as a request is done with when it's over.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `sleep()` is that the Apache worker threads get stalled while the sleep lasts and can't terminate so those 100 workers will be continuously held up by the attacker and legitimate users cannot log in to the site. The attacker only needs to make >33 requests/sec to make your site unable to process other login requests.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the comments seem to conflate "brute-force" with "distributed denial" attack. They are not the same. For an analysis of "brute-force", we need to consider only one attacker making a stream of requests in an effort to suss out a password.

Your use of `sleep` here is fine. Slowing down an online authorization process is a well-studied resistance feature. Rather than rehash what's been said, [see what Tom Leek said on security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40998/72365).

I might suggest something more intelligent, though. You don't really have an attack until you have evidence of repeated attempts. So you need to count attempts and slow down as a function of the attempts: more attempts, more delay. This means for your average user who gets say 3 attempts, they experience no artificial delay. But for more than say 3, you start adding in `max(32, 2^(n-3))` sleep -- that should be sufficient to ward off anyone trying an online brute-force attack.

Comment: Yeah, obviously a better solution is to make it progressively longer wait, require CAPTCHA after x failed tries, and full lockout after x amount of tries. But that requires a lot of code, and logging of all attempts(?).

I'm just thinking, isn't sleep() an incredibly easy way to drasticly reduce the chance of a successful attack? Of course there's better solutions, but it's way better than nothing - and probably sufficient for very small sites with limited requirements for security (e.g nothing sensitive).

Comment: @JamesB personally, I think no. If a hacker has all the time in the world (and they might with the use of automated scripts) then all a sleep will do is increase the time it will take to get in.

Comment: "That requires a lot of code..." It can, yes. But there are libraries to handle much of that heavy lifting, all the easier if you're using a readily available framework. Your small site may have nothing "sensitive", but don't conflate that with "valuable". If you're concerned enough to implement passwords properly (SSL, strong server-side hashes, safe reset), then be concerned enough to implement other defenses properly.

Answer (score 0):

I usually when I detect an unauthorized entry, I do a redirect.

```
header('Location: http://www.feedburner.com/myFeedXML');
die();
```

The idea is that the attacker takes a little time between request and request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method will slow down credential-stuffing attacks. It's a crude way of preventing a so-called timing attack, because it takes a fixed amount of time and reveals nothing about whether the password matched until it actually matched.  But, a two-second delay accepting a legitimate user is just rude to her.

Your scheme will also allow a credential stuffing attack to deny service to your legitimate users by jamming your server workers. Again, rude to your users.

And, with respect, your password validation scheme is grossly insecure. Please [read this.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) And please know that [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) is designed to resist timing attacks.

Please use the built in security stuff. Don't reinvent the wheel, because you'll actually reinvent the flat tire.
Don't make life easier for cybercreeps. Please.